# Sample from weighted histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, sample

I have a 2 column array, 1st column weights and the 2 nd column values which I am plotting using python. I would like to draw 20 samples from this weighted array, proportionate to their weights. Is there a python/numpy command which does that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
your_samples = numpy.random.choice(your_array[1], size=20, replace=False,
                                   p=your_array[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to refine your problem statement better. For example, if your array has only  1 row, what do you expect. If your array has 20,000 rows what do you expect? ...